# How to build executable with a compiler from ExternalProject

Tags: cmake

I have an external project that generates a compiler

```
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(gprolog
        GIT_REPOSITORY    "git@github.com:didoudiaz/gprolog.git"
        GIT_TAG           "master"
        SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty/gprolog"
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE   true
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND cd src && ./configure --with-install-dir=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty/gprolog-build
        BUILD_COMMAND     cd src && make
        INSTALL_COMMAND   cd src && make install
)
```

Consequently, I'd like to run:

```
add_executable(runner src/runner.c app/application.pro)
include_directories(runner "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty/gprolog-build/include")
```

but instead of `gcc` or `clang`, I need to use `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty/gprolog-build/bin/gplc`.

When I politely ask CMake to pretend that `gplc` is just another C compiler by adding

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty/gprolog-build/bin/gplc")
```

it screams at me with

```
Cannot get compiler information:
    Compiler exited with error code 1: .../gprolog/3rdparty/gprolog-build/bin/gplc -xc -g -isysroot ..../Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk -fpch-preprocess -v -dD -E
    Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.5.0
    Thread model: posix
    InstalledDir: .../XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
    clang: warning: -lm: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
    clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
    compilation failed
```

Comment: Might be worth a feature request to support the `gplc` compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of reverse engineering CMake's `enable_language` implementation modules to add your own for Prolog, you can always go the route of `add_custom_command` and ask your compiler to generate object files, which can be included as sources in the `add_executable` command.

If you add some detail to the question about how the Prolog compiler works, I can help you write the custom commands.

Comment: I've pushed example code here: https://github.com/vasily-kartashov/gprolog-cmake

Comment: I got it to work on my Ubuntu machine by providing an appropriate toolchain file and overrides file. See my PR here: https://github.com/vasily-kartashov/gprolog-cmake/pull/1/files